# What are some possible ways to store login details to create a site manager?

Tags: java, android, ftp

My app allows the saving and loading of a single ftp account with the login details (Site name,address,username, password,  port etc.) but I want to make a Site manager so the user can save multiple accounts. What are some ways to accomplish this? Not looking for code just some advice. I'll do the reading.

Comment: You can choose to use from either SharedPreferences or an SQLite Database. You can find more info about them here: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). In my opinion, a Database would serve your purpose a tad better that SharePrefs. Not much of a difference though.

Comment: Ah thanks. Yes from a quick glance at that doc Sqllite seems like the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [Authenticator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Authenticator.html) is the best choose. Take a look at this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/andsamples/concept-of-syncadapter-androidcontentabstractthreadedsyncadapter).

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Will start reading up on this class. Looks interesting